# UTF-16 to String in Java

Tags: java, string, utf-16

Let's say I have the word "Sample". In UTF-16 BE, this is represented as `00 53 00 61 00 6D 00 70 00 6C 00 65`. When I have this, I would like to convert it back to "Sample" using Java. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can convert a byte sequence to a String with a specified charset using [new String(array, charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the specified charset. The length of the new String is a function of
>   the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the byte
>   array.